# How to check if a string at a certain position contains character a-h?

Tags: java, if-statement, char

I know there must be a simpler way to check, but this is what I'm doing right now.

```
if (g.charAt(0) == 'a' || g.charAt(0) =='b' || g.charAt(0) =='c' ||
    g.charAt(0) == 'd' || g.charAt(0) =='e' || g.charAt(0) =='f' ||
    g.charAt(0) == 'g' || g.charAt(0) =='h')
```

Comment: You can assign `g.charAt(0)` to a variable to at least shorten this.

Comment: Remember that the letters are just values, in decimal: a = 97, b = 104. So you can also just check if your g.CharAt(0) are equal or between 97 and 104.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Relying on character ordering and that [a..h is a consecutive range](http://www.asciitable.com/):

```
char firstChar = g.charAt(0);
if (firstChar >= 'a' && firstChar <= 'h') {
   // ..
}
```

Comment: Not `&&` it should be `||`.

Comment: @tintinmj Not in this case, which is a range check for "between a and h, inclusive". Switching to `||` without applying DM would match everything :)

Comment: @tintinmj:  Read it another way:  `if('a' <= firstChar && firstChar <= 'h')`.  Now read it with `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Oops missed it. If `||` was used then *z* would be valid. Sorry for wrong comment.

Comment: @tintinmj in fact all characters would be…

Answer (score 29):

Use a regular expression for this one.  Cut the first character of your String as a substring, and match on it.

```
if(g.substring(0, 1).matches("[a-h]") {
    // logic
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A variation on hemanth's answer:

```
if("abcdefgh".contains(g.substring(0,1))) do_something();
```

or

```
if("abcdefgh".indexOf(g.charAt(0)) >= 0) do_something();
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it :

```
if(Array.asList("abcdefgh".toCharArray()).contains(g.charAt(0)))
{
  //Logic
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer a `Set` to a `List` since a `Set` has constant time access for `contains` (hash based).

Comment: @Makoto True, but how to convert a `String` to `Set` without converting it to a `List`? I believe we need to write our own method to do so.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you're missing the last step - converting it to a `Set` would give it slightly better performance.  But then, you get into the issue of the amount of work actually required to do something that's fairly trivial, and isn't a large set of data at all.  Or, you could do something with Guava and use `Sets.newHashSet('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h').contains(g.charAt(0))`.

Comment: `"abcdefgh".toCharArray()` won't work because it will make a `List<char[]>`. Also, of course create a static helper object. `Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')))`